# How to obtain PlainTeX in LaTeX environment?

Tags: plain-tex

In *The TeXbook* it is written that `\char13` is `<return>` and `\char32` is space.

But when I use this symbols I receive `fl` ligature for `\char13` and something like hyphen for `\char32`. What do I do wrong?

upd: I expected that if I typed `Hello\char13\char13{}there` I'll receive the two delimited paragraphs. I thought that \char13 could be replacement for the real `0x0D` carriage return symbol in TeX file.

Comment: Can you provide the page you referring too, please. I like to have a look on it. You might have misunderstood it. ASCII 13 is RETURN and ASCII 32 is SPACE, but this doesn't mean that the font has a symbol for it. Because RETURN and SPACE are not printable (as symbols) their positions are most likely used for symbols which don't have an ASCII number, like ligatures and special hyphens.

Comment: I get the same result in plain tex, so I guess you are mistaken here.

Comment: It's related to the font, so it should be the same for all TeX formats (e.g. plainTeX, LaTeX, ...) as long they use the same font.

Comment: Martin Scharrer: your comment look like the answer. Please recreate it as an answer, so I can check it as the correct one. TeXBook, ch. 8 btw

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The command `\char<number>` tells TeX: "Please, print character `<number>` from the current font". Font tables do not necessarily coincide with ASCII.

To get a `<return>` type the RET key, to obtain a `<space>` type SPC (i.e. the two keys corresponding to them).

If you want a *symbol* for return or space, that's a very different thing. For the space there is `\textvisiblespace`, for the return key you can say

```
\usepackage{dingbat}
```

and then you'll have available the command `\carriagereturn`.

There's also the **keystroke** package:

```
\usepackage{keystroke}
...
\Return \Spacebar
```

Comment: @outmind: You are welcome. egreg says all what I meant (and more), so there is no reason to turn my above comments to an answer.

Answer (score 2):

This shows the symbols for carriage return and space:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\char013
\char032
\end{document}
```

[image]